# How to do POW in local in Node js?

Tags: pow

How to do POW in local? I have tried to use ccurl.interface.js pkg in Node js then overriding the attachToTangle function in IOTA.lib.js. but keep getting - "Error: Request Error: Invalid trytes input"

Please see the stack trace below:

```
I: Starting search threads.
I: Found threads. Returning.
Error: Request Error: Invalid trytes input
at Object.requestError (/Users/bealox/Dropbox/Andy/Git/javascript/shoukoo/iota-query/node_modules/iota.lib.js/lib/errors/requestErrors.js:11:12)
at makeRequest.prepareResult (/Users/bealox/Dropbox/Andy/Git/javascript/shoukoo/iota-query/node_modules/iota.lib.js/lib/utils/makeRequest.js:291:24)
at exports.XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/bealox/Dropbox/Andy/Git/javascript/shoukoo/iota-query/node_modules/iota.lib.js/lib/utils/makeRequest.js:71:25)
at exports.XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (/Users/bealox/Dropbox/Andy/Git/javascript/shoukoo/iota-query/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
at setState (/Users/bealox/Dropbox/Andy/Git/javascript/shoukoo/iota-query/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:610:14)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/bealox/Dropbox/Andy/Git/javascript/shoukoo/iota-query/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:447:13)
at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
```

Comment: Please attach your code as well

Comment: Have you verified your input?